# Are the Decepticons counted as “Autobots” in the first live action movie?

Tags: transformers, transformers-live-action-series, transformers-2007

In the 2007 Transformers Live Action movie, Optimus Prime tells Samuel Witwicky,

> We are autonomous robotic organisms from the planet Cybertron

And Ratchet adds "but you can call us Autobots for short". Did Ratchet mean Autobot is a short form of "Autonomous Robotic organisms" or did he mention the name of his faction?

Are the Decepticons counted as Autobots in the live action movies?

Comment: Personally I think it was just a bad line. But in most continuities, the entire race was pretty much just Autobots until the "Decepticon" faction rose up and started the war. So if I'm reading your question right, then yes - technically the Decepticons were originally Autobots.

Comment: I’m having a hard time parsing the question. Do you mean: Are the Decepticons counted as “Autobots” in the first live action movie?

Comment: @RLH, yes, if they can also be called Autobots. In the cartoons series "Autobots" and "Decepticons" were the names of the factions. But here it seems Autobot is a synonymous of cybertronian robot or something